# How can I refactor my if-else statement?

Tags: c#

Well, I have a code here for my calculator but it seems so messy.

The logic here is when the display is equal to 0 the next input well replace the display except for 0 itself.
Just try seeing this image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtec2r6mcsmjvvt/refactor.jpg?dl=0

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num = btn1.Text;

        if (isEqual)
        {
            if (operator_pressed == true)
            {
                if (expr.EndsWith("0"))
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr = expr.Remove(expr.Length - 1, 1);
                    expr += num;
                }
                else
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    expr = "";
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (tbScreen.Text == "0")
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
                else
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    expr = "";
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (operator_pressed == true)
            {
                if (expr.EndsWith("0"))
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr = expr.Remove(expr.Length - 1, 1);
                    expr += num;
                }
                else
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (tbScreen.Text == "0")
                {
                    tbScreen.Clear();
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
                else
                {
                    tbScreen.Text += num;
                    expr += num;
                }
            }
        }

        isEqual = false;
        operator_pressed = false;

        btnEqual.Focus();
    }
```

Hoping for a positive response!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site - perhaps best if you take this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would recommend to post this question to codereview site. Also your code needs clarification. What is expr? Why its so important to check whether it ends with zero? What kind of data is stored in tbScreen? What are meanings of isEqual and operator_pressed variables?

Comment: expr stores expressions, like numbers and operators. isEqual is a bool if enter/equal button is pressed it would be true. Because there is a possibility that the answer would be zero, so if you input another digit then it will be replaced by the input one. tbScreen is a textbox where the initial result or the final result and the answer is display.operator_pressed same as isEqual if operator is pressed then it will return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should improve naming of your variables. It's not clear what the purpose of this method. I can only suggest that you are creating some kind of calculator. When you write your code business value should be clear, and when you ask to refactor code, you should explain *what* your code should do in business terms. E.g.

> I want to be able to type in math expression "1 + 5 - 2" then when I
>   press 'Equals' button I should see result of calculation and
>   expression in calculation history. This method calculates expression
>   result and updates controls. operator_pressed is a flag which is set
>   when user press some operator button. Etc

Without knowing purpose of your code I can only focus on removing duplicates. But intent is still will not be very clear for other developers. All your current code can be simplified to

```
num = btn1.Text;

if (IsInputStarted)
    tbScreen.Clear();

if (IsExpressionStarted)
    expr = "";

if (operator_pressed && expr.EndsWith("0"))
    expr = expr.Remove(expr.Length - 1, 1);

tbScreen.Text += num;
expr += num;
isEqual = false;
operator_pressed = false;

btnEqual.Focus();
```

With two properties (or you can use methods) extracted. One checks whether screen should be cleared:

```
private bool IsInputStarted
{
    get { return isEqual || operator_pressed || tbScreen.Text == "0";  }
}
```

Second verifies whether you should clear current expression

```
private bool IsExpressionStarted
{
    get
    {
        if (!isEqual)
            return false;

        if (operator_pressed)
            return !expr.EndsWith("0");

        return tbScreen.Text != "0";
    }
}
```

**Further recommendations** - do not mix your UI code (UI controls, UI events) with your business logic. These things should live and change separately. I would recommend you to create some kind of `Calculator` class which will be responsible for making calculations and storing expressions. And your code will look like

```
private void EqualsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double result = calculator.ExecuteExpression();
   resultsTextBox.Text = result.ToString();    
   historyListBox.Items.Add(calculator.Expression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this explanation easy and got some ideas to do things easy.

Comment: how about those numeric button? how would I implement it if I have to create a new class like you said sir?

ps. im just new and just starting to learning coding, sir. Thanks

Comment: also sir the word "flag" u mean? still can't capture all programming jargon

Comment: can you email me sir? kronikles24(at)gmail(dot)com. For if I still have question I can directly contact you. Thank you sir

Comment: also sir.. ..can you show me a little code about ExecuteExpression and Expression? and how would I make in button 0-1, and operator sign and the decimalpoint? even just a little so I can start recreate all mycodes.

Comment: @qwerzxcxyz 'flag' is a boolean variable which used to indicate state of something in your program. As a signal flags in real life. I wouldn't do anything when you typing numbers (each button press). Let them just stay on screen. You should send whole number to calculator class when you press some operator or equals button. For understanding what is Calculator class I suggest you to read articles about UI and business logic separation. Also google for UI patterns like MVC or MVP.  Calculator is a Model in your case.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92538/equal-button-function-in-calculator sir this is my post too at code review can you check it? and give some suggestion. Thanks\

Answer (score 1):

in your case I would suggest to think of a condition for every single action you want to perform.

When do you want to execute `tbScreen.Clear()`?

```
if (isEqual || operator_pressed || tbScreen.Text == "0" )
    tbScreen.Clear();
```

When do you want to execute `tbScreen += num;`? - always, so just write

```
tbScreen += num;
```

When do you want to execute `expr = "";`?

```
if (isEqual && ((operator_pressed && !expr.EndsWith("0")) || (!operator_pressed && tbScreen.Text != "0"))
   expr = "";
```

and so on..

you will get much shorter and easier to overlook code

Comment: Thanks to you too sir.. ..it kind of a help too